# Using gdalwarp to merge bands into a mosaic created by gdal_merge?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, mosaic, gdal-merge, gdalinfo

I have created a mosaic with gdal_merge.py using the following command:

```
gdal_merge.py -createonly -separate -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB -o merged.tif LE07_L1TP_046030_20180810_20180810_01_RT_b3.tif LE07_L1TP_046030_20180810_20180810_01_RT_b2.tif LE07_L1TP_046030_20180810_20180810_01_RT_b1.tif
```

It seems to create the mosaic no problem.  Now, when I run the gdalwarp command to create a viewable image (.tif), I get a red image, even though I am merging the color bands.  I am using this command:

```
gdalwarp --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 512 -wm 4096 -nomd LE07_L1TP_046030_20180810_20180810_01_RT_b3.tif LE07_L1TP_046030_20180810_20180810_01_RT_b2.tif  LE07_L1TP_046030_20180810_20180810_01_RT_b1.tif  merged.tif
```

The output of gdalinfo on merged.tif only gives me a red color band, where the other color band values are 0.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Also, I know I can use gdal_merge to do all of this at once, but I have a memory constraint that prevents me from using gdal_merge to do all of it at once.

gdalinfo output:

```
    Size is 9930, 9315
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["Albers",
    GEOGCS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010042,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],
    PROJECTION["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",29.5],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",45.5],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",23],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",-96],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (-2336089.094018519900000,2701776.184199890100000)
Pixel Size = (30.000000000000000,-30.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-2336089.094, 2701776.184) (125d42'39.19"W, 43d59'36.72"N)
Lower Left  (-2336089.094, 2422326.184) (124d40'18.81"W, 41d36'34.34"N)
Upper Right (-2038189.094, 2701776.184) (122d 7'21.46"W, 44d46' 3.96"N)
Lower Right (-2038189.094, 2422326.184) (121d11'45.22"W, 42d21'15.67"N)
Center      (-2187139.094, 2562051.184) (123d25'35.42"W, 43d11'34.14"N)
Band 1 Block=9930x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
    Computed Min/Max=0.000,255.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=27.268, StdDev=43.782
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=27.267951614063
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=43.781663272236
Band 2 Block=9930x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
    Computed Min/Max=0.000,0.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=0.000, Mean=0.000, StdDev=0.000
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0
Band 3 Block=9930x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
    Computed Min/Max=0.000,0.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=0.000, Mean=0.000, StdDev=0.000
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0
```

Is it overwriting the red band each time?  If so, is there a way I can select which color band each b*.tif goes to?

Comment: Gdalwarp does not merge bands. If you give several input files for it is writing them into the same mosaiced image but in your case all three images are in the same place and they really overwrite the old pixels. Use the merged image that you created as an input for gdalwarp. BTW quite many simple questions about GDAL today, are you all students taking the same classes?

Comment: Why don't you simply run gdal_merge.py without the `-createonly`switch?

Comment: @user30184 Thanks for the response.  I am not a student, but I may as well be. :)  I am going through the process of converting python scripts from Arcpy to GDAL.  My knowledge in the whole gis area is not super strong, but it's actually getting there thanks to this project.  I totally see what you are saying with the overwriting, rather than merging.  So, the reason I cannot run gdal_merge.py without the -createonly switch is because of memory.  I am developing for a server that only has 4GB of memory and when I run gdal_merge.py on the three bands, it fails and gives me a memoryError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after much hair being pulled out of my head, I figured out a solution!

There are two ways that I can think of to merge satellite image bands together.  The first one is to use `gdal_merge.py -separate`.  That's the easiest way to do it.  Now, if you are short on memory, there is another way.
Here are the steps I used:
1) You merge the bands with the -createonly flag

```
gdal_merge.py -createonly -separate -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB -o merged.tif redband.tif greenband.tif blueband.tif
```

2) Next, use gdalbuildvrt to create an xml.

```
gdalbuildvrt -separate merged.vrt redband.tif greenband.tif blueband.tif
```

3) Add the color bands into the new .vrt file.  Basically add the following lines after the following text in merged.vrt.
After `band="1">` add `<ColorInterp>Red</ColorInterp>`
After `band="2">` add `<ColorInterp>Green</ColorInterp>`
After `band="3">` add `<ColorInterp>Blue</ColorInterp>`

4) now use gdal_translate to merge the bands

```
gdal_translate merged.vrt merged.tif
```

Using `gdal_merge.py` without the `-createonly` switch would spike the memory usage to 2GB or more.  Using the method described here keeps the memory usage around 100MB, which is sufficient for my server.

A little more info - I did notice a difference in the `gdalinfo -hist` command when run on a `.tif` file created with `gdal_merge` vs the method above.  The `gdal_merge` tif has a ton of pixels at the beginning bucket, whereas the method above has all of the pixels spread out.  I'm thinking the spread out pixels is more accurate, so it might be better this way anyways.